# JQuery compare arrays for any match

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays

I'm having a pretty simple issue I think but I cannot get it solved.

On form submit I want to compare the values of two hidden input types and if any match is found return an alert to the user and prevent submit.  Pretty much the hidden input type values will be 1-3, could be 1, 12, 123, 13 etc.  So if 1 and 123, throw an alert.

So I've tried something like this, but I'm obviously confused about what I'm doing hehe.

```
 var new_products = $('#new_products');
 var array_new_products = jQuery.makeArray(new_products);
 var existing_products = $('#existing_products');
 var array_existing_products = jQuery.makeArray(existing_products);

 $("#my_form").submit(function(e) {

 if (jQuery.inArray(existing_products, new_products) >= 0) {
            e.preventDefault();
            alert ("This Promotion matches one or more products already associated to this Group.  If you continue the existing Promotion will be cancelled and replaced with the currently selected Promotion!");
 }
 return true;
 });
```

I'm open to doing this by comparing strings and returning matches or anything really.  I'm just pretty new to Jquery.  Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.each($('#new_products').val().split(''), function(i, char) {
    var existing = $('#existing_products').val();

    if (existing.indexOf(char) != -1)
        alert('mathces found');
});
```

checks if any of the characters in the returned value from `#new_product` exists in the value returned from `#existing_products` ?

Comment: You can't call `.each()` on the result of `.split()`. Did you mean `.forEach()`? Or did you mean to use `$.each` instead?

Comment: Beautiful, thanks you very much.  Working like a champ now.  I been screwing with it since like 2pm EST :(.   +1 for the correction haha.  I was like why...wont...this...work ?!?!?!